# выделение текста (хэштега) внутри поля ввода

Tags: javascript, input, hashtag

как можно выделить текст в input[type="text"] во время ввода (как в facebook, twitter), например выделить хэштеги.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретно в `<input>` не получится, т.к. для выделения хэштегов их необходимо оборачивать в теги, а `<input>` не может содержать в себе теги, он не является элементом-контейнером.

Существует аттрибут [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable), который можно применить к элементам-контейнерам, таким как `<div>`, по сути добавляющий поведение `<input>` и при этом оставляющий основные характеристики самого элемента `<div>`.

```
<div class="hashtag-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Воспользовавшись этим, можно повесить обработчик на ввод данных в `<div>` и заменять "хэштегоподобные" слова на отформатированные элементы.

```
var input = document.querySelector('.hashtag-input');

input.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {

    // забираем только текст, без тегов
    var text = this.textContent;

    // заменяем
    var highlighted = text.replace(/(#\w+)/g, '<span class="hashtag">$1</span>');

    // обновляем содержимое
    this.innerHTML = highlighted;

    // установка курсора в конец строки
    placeCaretAtEnd(this);
});
```

Во-первых прошу обратить внимание на регулярное выражение:

```
text.replace(/(#\w+)/g, '<span class="hashtag">$1</span>')
```

Здесь каждое (`/g`) слово (`\w`), которое начинается символом `#` будет заменено на тег `<span>`, с текстом этого слова и символом `#` перед ним внутри.

Также, используется функция `placeCaretAtEnd()`, чтобы помочь устанавливать курсор в конец строки, т.к. при замене всего содержимого он может соскакивать, код для нее в [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vowotoyeka/1/edit?html,js,output), позаимствован [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4238971/1573638).

[Здесь](http://jsbin.com/vowotoyeka/1/edit?html,js,output)  можно увидеть весь код.